# How to reduce verbosity in the xgboost package for Julia

Tags: julia, xgboost

How can I reduce verbosity in the Julia package for xgboost (`XGBoost`)?
I have set `print_every_n => Int(0)` and `verbosity=0` but I still get the info for every boosting step. I use the package version 2.2.1 in Julia v1.8.2. There is a newer package version, and I can not upgrade at the moment. However I doubt that this is an issue of the package version.

The following is an example. It always prints train-rmse for each iteration (of the 50 in this example). How can I supress this?

Thank you!

```
using XGBoost

nobs = Int(10000)
num_feat = Int(20)

x_train = rand(T, nobs, num_feat)
y_train = rand(T, size(x_train, 1))

params_xgb = Dict(
    :max_depth => Int(2),
    :eta => 0.01,
    :objective => "reg:squarederror",
    :print_every_n => Int(0)
)

dtrain = DMatrix(x_train, y_train .- 1)
@time m_xgb = xgboost(dtrain, num_round=50, verbosity=0, param = params_xgb);
pred_xgb = XGBoost.predict(m_xgb, x_train);
size(pred_xgb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xgboost(dtrain, num_round=50, verbosity=0, param = params_xgb, watchlist=(;));
```

see: https://github.com/dmlc/XGBoost.jl/issues/151

Comment: Quoting from the link: `bst = xgboost((X, y), watchlist = (;)) ;` works (key is to have `watchilist = (;)` bit.

Comment: thanks, I just got the same answer on github. I am sorry that I did not find it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. I've used `watchlist=(;)` with success. Initially, I had similar confusion until realized many code blocks on the internet are from an earlier version of xgboost.jl. The key words 'verbosity' and 'param' are no longer part of the package and ignored. I believe the model in the code block above is created with the default parameter values. My practice is to pass in the xgboost hyperparameter keywords individually. However, if one wishes to duplicate the `param=` functionality the `params_xgb` dictionary could be converted to a named tuple, with for example `kw=(;params_xgb...)` , and can then be passed in to xgboost with `; kw...` and the end of the parameter list.